# Node position stuck at origin

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Could someone explain to me why my node's position is stuck at the origin. It seems that only the devices that are 375x667 have this problem all the other devices when I run this code in the simulator work fine

```
//enemy
        enemy.size = enemyTexture.size()
        enemy.setScale(0.75)
        enemy.zPosition = 2
        enemy.position = CGPoint(x: 230, y: -40)
        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemyTexture, size: CGSize(width: enemy.size.width, height: enemy.size.height))
        enemy.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
        enemy.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        enemy.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionNum.enemyNum.rawValue
        enemy.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = CollisionNum.swordNum.rawValue
        enemy.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisionNum.swordNum.rawValue
```

UPDATE: (Response to George_E_2 )

```
if screenSize.height == 375{ //iphone X
        bg.size = CGSize(width: 812, height: 375)

 enemy.size = enemyTexture.size()
 enemy.setScale(0.75)
 enemy.position = CGPoint(x: 230, y: -40)
 enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemyTexture, size: CGSize(width: enemy.size.width, height: enemy.size.height))
 enemy.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
 enemy.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
 enemy.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CollisionNum.enemyNum.rawValue
 enemy.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = CollisionNum.swordNum.rawValue
 enemy.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CollisionNum.swordNum.rawValue
```

In order to support other devices I first checked to see what device the user is using then base the positions on said device. Im fairly new to SpriteKit and Swift so I thought that manually inputing coordinates would be a bit better. For example with the code that I used for the iphone X everything is scaled and placed correctly, but with any device that has a resolution of 375X667 all the nodes are placed at the origin